# Does forcing air through ever expanding pockets cool it?

Tags: air

If 30c air is pulled apart then forced back together repeatedly under extraction would this result in a cooling of the air as the energy is lost through a process of constant change?. What kind of pressures would need to be created to cool it sufficiently to 12c.

Comment: Can you expand your answer to make it clear what process you are talking about. For example is it a Joule expansion? Just expanding and compressing a given volume of ideal gas will not change its temperature.

Comment: @JohnRennie: This is a question, not an answer, but I agree there should be more detail here.